# Determine whether N is fibonacci or not, if not find the largest fibonacci number smaller than N

Tags: python, math

How can I determine whether a given number `N` is a fibonacci number or not, if that number is not a fibonacci number how can I*determine the largest fibonacci number smaller than `N`?

I found the solution via generating the series of fibonacci number with limit `N`.

Is there any better way to do this in Python?

guys consider while DOWN VOTES, I've accepted the solution provided here. I do not think it as worthwhile since I have posted what I need and got the solution from you guys.

Thank You.

Comment: This is not question about *how* to do this in Python (or any other programming language) but about the proper algorithm.

Comment: nop, I thought of the problem and tried to get the solution. I did it in conventional way i.e. _generating the series of fibonacci number with limit N_. I need some optimized or better way of doing the same in PYTHON.

Comment: http://en.literateprograms.org/Fibonacci_numbers_%28Python%29

Comment: I still can't see why this is a Python question. Please add your Python code to your question if you want Python advice. If you want to talk about the proper algorithm, add it in pseudo code.

Comment: @Tichodroma:thank you for the suggestion. if we can generate algorithm we can get the solution.

Comment: reads like homework ;). A few pointer: If you have to do the comparison often it may be better to generate the numbers once and store them in an array. there are approximation formulas for large fibonacci numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple test for whether some integer `N` is a Fibonacci number is as follows:

```
N is a Fibonacci number iff either (5 * n^2 + 4) or (5 * n^2 - 4) is a square number.
```

See here for the ingenious proof (page 417): http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/10-4/advanced10-4.pdf

If it turns out that `N` is not a Fibonacci number, then the simplest method is just to keep trying with smaller numbers until you find one, although this could take a very long time for large `N`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general algorithm:
The naive way is to solve it with recursion - but in terms of run time complexity it's not useful at all.
Create a new array, let's call it FibArr .
Insert 1,1, to the the array.
Then , the value of the i'th index in the array is fibArr[i-1]+fibArr[i-2] (i>=3)
In every iteration check whether the new value inserted into fibArr==N.
If true , return.
Else, check whether the inserted value is bigger then N.
If true , assuming now fibArr has k values,  return the (k-1) value.
Else , keep iterating :)

*With python it's even easier to do - but notice that in python there are no arrays , but lists.
It's easier with python becuase you don't have to set the list length, like in java.